Impact of increasing frequency on a faraday cage
I've been doing a couple experiments on the above. I've created a faraday cage with metal mesh and continuous, conductive material. I'm using a primary solenoid connected to a signal generator(AC) to increase the frequency. The primary solenoid is placed near to a secondary solenoid which is placed on the inside of the cage and I'm trying to induce a voltage into the secondary coil using a changing magnetic field through the use of AC at the primary coil which creates an electric field. I expected the cage to increase in shielding effectiveness against the changing magnetic field as the frequency increased, however I'm confused due to the first part of the data. The trend goes as the frequency increases from 0 - 2000 Hz the voltage induced increases and as the frequency continues increasing from 2000-11000, the voltage induced drops at a increasing rate. Can anyone explain this trend?

Resonance, probably? It might help to include a graphic of the circuit.

And you are expecting the Faraday cage to do what, exactly, to the magnetic field?

Hey, made the former changes, resonance might be possible, ill include a graphic as soon as I can.
